# Sliding from left to right instead of fading safari css issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, safari

I have a scrolling header that after 80 px gets fixed and starts scrolling.
The issue is in safari where it start scrolling but starts from left to right instead of just fading like on other browsers.

```
<header>
  This bis the header
</header>

$(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('header').addClass('scrolling-header');
    var offset = $(document).scrollTop();
    if (offset < 80) {
        $('header').removeClass('scrolling-header');
    }
});

.scrolling-header {
    position: fixed;
    background: #FFF;
    opacity: 0.85;
    width: 100%;
    transform: all;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -moz-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.8s;
    transition-duration: 0.8s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

Fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/uohLdwok/1/

Comment: I am thinking that it has to do with `-webkit-transform`, tested but not getting any results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue, it was because you need to add `-webkit-transition-property: opacity, background, position; without` width, it seams that safari interprets every property if you say all.